# opening, manipulating and rendering SVG files in win32 (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, svg, cairo

I would like to open SVG files, manipulate the shapes defined in those and render those shapes to the screen in windows (vista/7/...).

I work with C++ builder. I've been thinking of using cairo or agg to render the shapes but I need a SVG parser library that provides a renderer and a full access to the shapes defined in the SVG files.

Does anyone know a library I could use to achieve this ?

I can't use Qt for money reason.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried googling for C++ svg libraries?

Comment: Yes I did but there's plenty of exotic solution, I would to find a robust way to do it. I know there's some SVG parser but I also need to find one which include a SVG renderer, cause I dont' have enough time to write the renderer. I've been adding a look to rsvg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do so, is I think, librsvg with libcairo. Both are very feature rich and easy to use. I can open several SVG, render them to the screen and handle them to scale and move them.

Answer (score 1):

The AGG source includes an SVG viewer :-)

Even if you are writing a commercial product the Qt licence should be fine.

Comment: Yes but it's not very up-to-date. I tried to display a svg file which includes a gradient fill and AGG SVG viewer can't display it while rsvg SVG viewer can.

Comment: The only other source I can think of is InkScape but if Qt LGPL is prohibitive then InkScape GPL certainly will be!

Answer (score 0):

The generic "render SVG to a cairo context" solution is librsvg: https://live.gnome.org/LibRsvg

However, both Qt and librsvg are licensed under LGPL (which does NOT forbid you to use it in commercial products).

Comment: yeap, as I commented in the first message i've been having a look at this library which seems to be up-to-date and very good.

Comment: Is it possible to install librsvg on windows machine. I am trying to get it work with image magick api.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently put together a small SVG renderer library in C++: https://github.com/igagis/svgren

It uses Cairo for rendering to off-screen surface. Supports gradients and all kind of shapes.
It uses another my library called svgdom which actually loads and offers a DOM of SVG which can be manipulated before rendering.